# SpringMail not sending attachment for html messages

Tags: spring, attachment

I'm using SpringMail to send html mails with attachment but either html message is going or if attachment is there, mail shows html code. Please tell me what is missing here. If I uncomment **message.setContent**, attachment won't go. Here is my code:

```
try{
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper helper;

        try {
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
            //message.setContent(text, "text/html");

            helper.setFrom(from);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(text);

            if(hasAttachment){
                FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(filePath);

                helper.addAttachment(fileName, file);                   
            }

            mailSender.send(message);
        }
        catch(AddressException aex){
            System.out.println("Cannot send : " + aex.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not sending " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Could not send : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it working. Remove the comment line. Change:

helper.setText(text);

to

helper.setText(text, true);             // here true means HTML message